# Snipping audio with soundcloud

Tags: ios, audio, soundcloud

I'm looking for a simple way to snip streamed songs from soundcloud.

I was looking throughout their iOs API but couldn't find a way to do it with it, though there are apps like pingtune that are doing it and I'm wondering how.

I'm basically looking for a more convenient way to do it rather than using the iOs audio SDK. So for example, I'm wondering if I can easily upload to soundcloud (or any other service for that matter) a snip of an existing song that is constructed of a song in their DB + vars for start and end time.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this `AVAssetExportSession` document on Exporting a Trimmed Audio Asset: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1730/_index.html

If you want to do this in an app, you could hit the SoundCloud API for a download link to the file you want to cut up (or grab the 128kbps streaming link if there is no download link available), and use `CMTime` to specify the in and outpoints.